# How can I access the audio 'Priority Mode' on a device running Android 5.0?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Android 5.0 includes a new way to control which apps are allowed to make noise on your device: when you press the volume button, the popup now lets you to choose **None** (completely silent), **Priority** (only priority notifications make sound), or **All** (everything is allowed to make noise.)

[image: New 'priority mode' controls in Android 5.0]

I would like my app to be able to query the device to find out which of these three modes is currently active, and also I would like to be able to change these modes (without requiring the device to be rooted).   Does anyone know how to do this?

So far, all I can find is a brief reference [on this changelog](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html):

> Setting the device to RINGER_MODE_SILENT causes the device to enter the new priority mode. The device leaves priority mode if you set it to RINGER_MODE_NORMAL or RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE.

This works as described, which allows me a very limited ability to change "priority mode" by modifying the [ringer mode in AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setRingerMode(int)).  That's not enough, though, as I need to be able to know exactly which of the three priority mode settings is currently active, and it would also be nice if I could change them more precisely than AudioManager allows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found a solution, but this requires root to change, because this setting is in Settings.Global.

Name of setting is "zen_mode".

Values are:

```
ZENMODE_ALL = 0;
ZENMODE_PRIORITY = 1;
ZENMODE_NONE = 2;
```

EDIT: I've found another solution. Check NotificationListenerService.requestInterruptionFilter(int interruptionFilter).  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html
Implementation example: https://github.com/kpbird/NotificationListenerService-Example

Comment: That solves most of my problem, I just need to use a ContentObserver to watch Settings.Global for changes.  At least now I can tell when the user changes these settings.  Thanks!

Comment: Pretty hide... But working as expected. Many thanks! Just to point out one thing, `requestInterruptionFilter` is the one for changing the mode, to just query the current mode you can use getCurrentInterruptionFilter: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#getCurrentInterruptionFilter() . Unfortunately, all of this requires the user to give special permission to your app.

Comment: I've used Global Settings check in my apps, but there are a problem with OnePlus 2 (Oxygen ROM), that is using other values. In concrete, is using 3 for ZENMODE_ALL, 1 for ZENMODE_NONE and 2 for ZENMODE_PRIORITY. Is possible to check what ROM is using the device in order to see a values or other?